# why for azure function, Incoming HTTP requests can't use the inbound IP address to call individual functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

There is situation that access azure function http trigger behind a firewall, but we cannot use the ip to access http endpoint as in [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses?tabs=portal#function-app-inbound-ip-address), anyone knows why? how is azure http trigger is designed?
I want to call http trigger with an ip address, How can I do that

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you provide more details. Are you expecting your http trigger function to make a call back to the system that made the http request - it will not likely be allowed by your firewall. You should look at Azure SignalR for such scenarios[server calling the client]

Comment: Thanks for comment, I want to call http trigger with an ip address, How can I do that

Comment: Do you want to get the client ip (remote) address for accessing the individual function in an azure function app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure is using name-based virtual hosting which means multiple web apps (and functions) are hosted on the same pool of servers and share the same IP addresses. As a consequence, Azure needs an additional property to determine which function should be called when an HTTP request is sent to an IP address and this is achieved by setting the HTTP "Host" header.

To get the inbound IP of your function run the following in a terminal

```
nslookup <YourName>.azurewebsites.net
```

Assuming the IP address returned here is 20.51.3.70 you can then send an HTTP request to this IP but you have to specify the "Host" header like so:

```
curl -i -H "Host: <YourName>.azurewebsites.net" http://20.51.3.70/api/<FunctionName>?code=<APIKey>
```